# Is using FileLock necessary to avoid issues with Reading & Writing or Writing & Writing at the same time?

Tags: android, file, synchronization, locking

I'm designing an app that whose main thread interacts with a .txt file by reading and writing to it.

This app also has a background IntentService that will read and write to this file.

I need to be able to read a file in, and write it back with new data, all while guaranteeing that another thread has not altered the file's data inbetween these two steps.

I think a FileLock is what I want, but I am having trouble locking onto the file when I begin to read from it, as InputFileStream.getChannel().lock() gives an exception. (NonWritableChannelException).

I want the code to go something like:

```
File theFile = new File(file.txt);
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(theFile);

//should block here if it can't immediately lock
FileLock fileLock = in.getChannel().lock(); 

String inString = "";

int content;
while((content = in.read()) != -1){
    inString += Character.toString(((char) content));
 }
in.close();

inString += "new data";

out = new FileOutputStream(file);

out.write(finalString.getBytes());

 out.flush();
 out.close();

//releases the lock
fileLock.release();
```

One scenario I realized might work was using a RandomAccessFile. Because when reading from those, you can declare them "rw" permissions (read write), so you can use .getChannel().lock() But I figured I'd ask the community before diving into that.

Comment: "I'm designing an app that whose main thread interacts with a .txt file by reading and writing to it. This app also has a background IntentService that will read and write to this file." -- why? Why not have a single entity with a work queue that is responsible for writes and either reads or returning cached data? Also, I hope that when you refer to the "main thread" doing reads that you do not mean that you are doing disk I/O on your main application thread, as that is going to cause jank.

Comment: These are small files (a couple hundred characters). Why have background threads accessing the files? Because its an app that does things in the background of your phone at a scheduled time using AlarmManager. It needs to do Internet downloads, which can't be run in A broadcast reciever class, so the broadcast reciever class has to run up an intentservice whose purpose is to check a file online. If a condition has occured, it needs to write to the file that the user interface reads, so that the info can be shown to the user.

Comment: This post was poorly named. A better title would have been: How to modify a file all while ensuring no other thread can modify it?

Comment: "If a condition has occured, it needs to write to the file that the user interface reads, so that the info can be shown to the user" -- and that is what I am suggesting could be redesigned. Particularly for small files, use an in-memory cache, backed by a file. Your service updates the file and uses an in-process event bus to let the UI layer know, if it currently exists, that the data changed. The only time you need to read the file is when your process is started anew, and if you do that in the same `IntentService` that does the writes, the I/O is automatically serialized.

Comment: You're right! Okay, so I had this file that kept track of running alarm managers, and this file also had 'updated' data that the threads would write to it. The UI had to change this file when a new AlarmManager was created.     Instead, I will move this changing data into a seperate file that the interface will only read, and no longer have to write to.

Comment: CommonsWare, if you submit your answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, for a single-process app (which most Android apps are), thread synchronization is the route to go, more so than filesystem-level locking.

Beyond that, in general, you want to minimize disk I/O, because that's slow.

Particularly for small files, use an in-memory cache, backed by a file. Your service updates the file and uses an in-process event bus (`LocalBroadcastManager`, greenrobot's EventBus, Square's Otto) to let the UI layer know, if it currently exists, that the data changed. The UI layer focuses on using the in-memory cache for the data.

The only time you need to read the file is when your process is started anew, and if you do that in the same `IntentService` that does the writes, the I/O is automatically serialized. If your UI detects, on startup, that the in-process cache is empty, it just sends a command to kick off the service to read in that cache. Once again, the service uses the event bus to let the UI layer know that the data is now ready for use.

This way, you cut your disk reads down to the minimum required, plus you synchronize your disk I/O (`IntentService` only uses one thread and has a work queue if multiple commands come in around the same time), so you don't have to worry about part of your app clobbering what the rest of your app is doing.

Comment: I have never used caching - I will have to try it once my prototype is working. Currently my UI instantiates a FileObserver, and passes it a handler running on Looper.getMainLooper(). The file observer instance passes a message to the handler when a file is changed. When the handler's handleMessage fires, the UI is updated. This works for now. Thanks!

Comment: I've had a new revelation about your answer. Except for the fact that everything is (kind of) stored in one place(the harddisk), we have the abstraction of different files. They make it so we can separate our "conversations" in our programs. Writing and reading to the same file from two different threads is like trying to talk while someone else is talking. Simply speak on different channels! AKA write to different files, and read from different files. You read from A and write to B. They read from B and write to A!

Comment: Ended up solving this with mutexes and SQLite

Answer (score 1):

Using the Random Access File might lead to slow performance.

As per this link - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#RandomAccessFile%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29

```
"rws"   Open for reading and writing, as with "rw", and also require that every update to the file's content or metadata be written synchronously to the underlying storage device.
"rwd"   Open for reading and writing, as with "rw", and also require that every update to the file's content be written synchronously to the underlying storage device.
```

File content if written to the device would be significantly slower than the other methods.

Also as far as your NonWritableChannelException is concerned, it occurs because you are trying to lock inputstream. If you want to lock, you need to open the file for write.

Hope this helps.